# Grid component and sorting with custom sort listener

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using grid component and default column sort behavior doesnt work for me correctly. I'm using a paged data so current grid data content is just a part of the entire data set. And default sorting feature sorts only data on screen and I need send the sort options to my database query. For this I added custom sort listener as on the example ...

```
e.g. grid.addSortListener(e -> this.sortListener(e));
```

... so I can catch the sort order change user does on screen which works fine. But how can I disable the default sorting the Vaadin does in grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Grid`  redirects the sort to `Container.sort()` so you could override this method in your `Container` and ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

David Marko,

You will you that following code

**grid.sort("Column Name", SortDirection.ASCENDING);**

It was working well